# Why does custom function create an error but console.log doesn't on click event?

Tags: javascript

I have two identical `<div>` elements with different listeners **onClick** event.

```js
function onclick() {
    console.log("onclick");
}
```

```css
.some-styles {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div 
  id="fisrt" 
  class="some-styles" 
  onclick="onclick()"
>
  Click the text to see in the console
</div>
<div 
  id="second" 
  class="some-styles" 
  onclick="console.log('without error')"
>
  Click the text to see in the console
</div>
```

The `#first` `<div>` uses the custom function `onclick()` which creates `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

The `#second` `<div>` uses `console.log()` function which doesn't create any error.

Regarding to the above info I have one question:

1) Why does **the custom function** create the error and **console.log** doesn't?

Comment: try renaming your function

Comment: In the context of an inline event handler, "onclick" refers to the surrounding automatically generated function and not your custom onclick function.  Solution:  don't call it onclick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `onxxx` attributes to create event handler functions, you get a function constructed with a complicated scope. Among the things that will be in scope for the code of your handler function (that is, the code in the attribute text) is the element involved; in this case the `<div>`.  All the properties of the `<div>` will be available as local symbols to your event handler code, notably including the `onclick` property.

Thus your code is not calling the function you've declared as (presumably) the global symbol `onclick`, it's calling the `onclick` function registered with the `<div>`, which is of course your handler code. It's therefore an infinite recursive call that overflows the stack.

If you change the name of your handler function to `romanRoman()` or something else that doesn't exist as a property on the clicked element or any enclosing `<form>`, then things will work better.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Could you also provide some links to where it's documented?(if it exists)

Comment: Great! But what’s ‘onxxx’ attribute? Could you show, please, in code.

Comment: @StepUp like `onclick`, `onchange`, `onblur`, etc — the attributes on HTML elements that one can use to set up event handlers.